# 120 volt wiring problem

Tags: electrical

I have a wiring problem after replacing an outside outlet.   I checked my wires with a multimeter,  Hot is 121v, the common shows good and ground is good.

When I place a plug in 3 light tester it indicates wiring is correct. I show 121v with meter on hot and common.  Also on hot and ground. But, nothing works. Not even a 5w night light.this line goes through a GFI outlet. Which tests good, and when tripped also shuts off new outlet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a high resistance connection somewhere. Try plugging in both the 3-light tester and a light to the outlet. I expect that then, the tester will indicate something wrong. If all of the lights go out, the problem is on the hot. If it shows an open neutral, then the problem is on the neutral.

I’d suggest you remove the outlet and check all of the connections. Also, if you are using the back-stabs, you should switch to the screw connections instead. These are much more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will try that. I am not a fan of the stab connections.  I have checked the screw connections first.